Drop unused metrics from prometheus
I have many unused metrics on our Prometheus server, and to reduce storage utilization, I want to remove these unused metrics. I have identified a few unused metrics and now wish to drop them all.
I used the following configuration to remove the unused metrics, but it seems that these metrics are still available on the Prometheus server
relabel_configs:
- source_labels: [__name__]
  regex: "container_processes|watch_cache_capacity"
  action: drop


Please help.
Thanks
I want above mentioned metrics to be dropped or it should not be listed in promethues server if i query it

This is a valid question. Idk why it was closed.  If you are looking to delete timeseries metrics then should look into the admin api Delete Series.
